# onActivityResult NOT called in MainActivity from previous Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I know this is a basic question and I have seen multiple answers on it in stackoverflow but I seem to be stuck still. The onActivityResult is just not being called.

Here is my code:

1> In MainActivity I have onActivityResult

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements MasterListFragment.OnImageClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Entering onActivityResult");

    }
}
```

2> In my second activity I have this

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("myData1", "Data 1 value");
        data.putExtra("myData2", "Data 2 value");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
    }
```

I do a Log and the Log statement is not displayed in the LOGCAT

Comment: Do you start second activity like, `startActivityForResult(Intent)`?

Comment: Hi if u re Using Fragment try below link:  https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/onactivityresult-in-fragment/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting result back in OnActivityResult you should use `startActivityForResult(Intent,REQ_CODE)` method for starting your second activity.

Comment: thanks! this has solved my problem. I was only calling my second activity with startActivity(intent).

Comment: glad from hear that. Mark answer as accepted if you found your solution from answer so that others can find solution easily. @ZandroZulueta

Answer (score 2):

On Your MainActivity Open A Intent Like this:

```html
Intent intent = new Intent(this,"Your c class name.class");
 startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

and in your Second Activity do this:

```html
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
  returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);//your changed value here
  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
  finish();
```

The again in your MainActivity do this

```html
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        String result=data.getStringExtra("result");

        //you will get the changed data here
      }
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
          //Write your code if there's no result
     }
  }
  }//onActivityResult
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);`