# Can't pass data from second Activity to main

Tags: java, android

I am having a trouble in passing data between Activity2 and ActivityMain.
I have ActivityMain with a "Add Person" button. When I press this button, I go to Activity2, after that I fill field Name and press button "Add", but can't to add Name on my ActivityMain.

ActivityMain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Person"
    android:onClick="addPerson"
   />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

ActivityMain.java

```
package com.example.test.zadanie01;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(PersonActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);
        setContentView(textView);
}

public void addPerson(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PersonActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
}
```

Activity2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/send_name"/>
   <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Person"
        android:onClick="addPersonToMain"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity2.java

```
package com.example.test.zadanie01;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

public class PersonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_person);
}

public void addPersonToMain(View view){
    Intent returnintent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    EditText SendName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.send_name);

    String message = SendName.getText().toString();
    returnintent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnintent);
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52361315/6541643 refer this answer

Comment: both solution doesn't work for me, see my code, guys

Answer (score -1):

Change this part of your code.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == 1){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String message = data.getStringExtra(PersonActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setTextSize(40);
                textView.setText(message);
                setContentView(textView);
            }
        }
}
```

You don't need to create another `Intent` in `onActivityResult`, the Intent is already delivered by the method: `Intent data`. Then use data as your intent. And before all, check if it is the requestCode you asked and if the result is OK.

**EDIT**

Answering another part of the question from the comments.

1 - Add a TextView to your activity_main.xml and set its visibility to gone by default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/text_message"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textSize="40sp"
 android:visibility="gone" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Person"
    android:onClick="addPerson"
   />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

2 - When retrieveng the data message, show the TextView and display the content.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == 1){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String message = data.getStringExtra(PersonActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

                TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_message);
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView.setText(message);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: it works fine, but i see just my message, where is the button from main activity?

Comment: I edited the question with a solution to this problem. Check it.

Comment: Thank you, @Soon Santos, but i tied to search and find AdapterList, I need it)

Answer (score -1):

try to replace

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(PersonActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

with

```
String message = data.getStringExtra(PersonActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: it works fine, but i see just my message, where is the button from main activity?

Comment: in this line setContentView(textView);
you replaced the layout by your textview
instead you can add textview to your linear layout and in activity result set the textview text with the resulting one

Comment: Thank you, @Hazem Ashraf, but i tied to search and find AdapterList, I need it)